# Nested foreach loop seq() output in r

Tags: r, foreach, int, seq

Consider the following code:

```
space<- 2
years<- 4

year<- foreach(1:years, .combine = rbind)%:%
  foreach(1:space, .combine = rbind)%do% seq(1:years)

year

         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
result.1    1    2    3    4
result.2    1    2    3    4
result.1    1    2    3    4
result.2    1    2    3    4
result.1    1    2    3    4
result.2    1    2    3    4
result.1    1    2    3    4
result.2    1    2    3    4
```

Why is it returning the output as an `int[1:8, 1:4]`? The output I am looking for should be `int[1:8, 1]` and look like this:

```
         [,1] 
result.1    1 
result.2    1 
result.1    2 
result.2    2 
result.1    3 
result.2    3 
result.1    4 
result.2    4
```

The reason I want it to return something in this format is that I am performing many other nested `foreach` loops which are dependant on the iterators of `space` and `year` and `space` needs to be recorded as `result.n`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return `seq(1:years)` for each combination (4x2 = 8) of two (unnamed) sequences.

To get the result you want, you need

```
year <- foreach(year = 1:years, .combine = rbind) %:%
  foreach(1:space, .combine = rbind) %do% year
```